# Spring - Abstracting url mapping to handle common url parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Assume the following setup:

We have multiple commands mapped to different URLs, each of these with its own body, which we can capture using mappings, like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "url1/{param}/command", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Response command1(@PathVariable("param") String param,
                         @RequestParam(value = urlParam) Param urlParam,
                         @RequestBody Request request) {
    ...}
```

We have several cases where the same parameter repeats in several urls, specifically the URL parameter. Since we have several such variables, today we manually add them to each mapping which is error prone and too verbose.

Is there anyway of routing all mappings through an initial mapping, capturing all those url parameters, and thus remove the clutter from all other mappings?

Answer (score 0):

If you switch from Spring MVC to any JAX-RS framework (e.g. Jersey, Apache Wink), you can use subresources:

```
@Path("/parent/{id}")
class ParentResource {


  @Path("/child1")
  Child1Resource getChild() {
  ....
  }

  @Path("/child2")
  Child2Resource getChild() {
  ....
  }
}
```

Pay attention that methods with @Path annotations are not annotated with HTTP Methods, so any relevant HTTP request matching the url will propagate into the subresources.

Another suggestion to reduce the error-proning: use constants (public final static String) as parameters both when you create the url and when you use the parameter. This makes it a little bit more verbose, but reduce the error-proning. It can be used both with Spring-MVC and JAX-RS. Don't forget that it's possible to put constants inside the annotation values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We use constants already, but the method signatures are still extremely ugly